# Binomial matching (RF & microwave)

Tags: rf, impedance-matching, microwave

In a Binomial Matching Transformer, we're expecting the reflection coefficient to be the following function:

**\$\Gamma(\theta)=A(1+e^{-2j\theta})^N\$**

What is the philosophy behind assuming this function for a maximally flat response?

Comment: What is a "Binomial Matching Transformer" - please give details.

Comment: A Binomial Matching Transformer is a series combination of few transmission line stubs which connects two different impedance TLs and in such a way that reflection is minimized (ideally no reflection) in some design bandwidth.    Topic Reference: Microwave Engineering - 3rd Edition, D.M.Pozar, page.246. @Andyaka